# Why do I get a warning that says " each child in a list should have a unique key prop" but I already have a unique key prop for the child component

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and doing a code along on an online course. I am getting a warning of each child on a list should have a unique key prop. The child component however already has a unique key prop.

The program should increase the value of an object value, in this case counter.value by one when the increment button is pressed but I am getting a key error.

I have tried adding (argument, index) to the map function that I am using but i get an error that the child component is not defined.

```
//Parent Component

import React, { Component } from "react";
import Counter from "./counter";

class Counters extends Component {
  state = {
    counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 9 },
     ]
  };

  handleIncrement = counter => {
    const counters = [...this.state.counters];
    const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
    counters[index] = { ...counters };
    counters[index].value++;
    this.setState({ counters });
  };


   render() {
    return (
      <div>

        {this.state.counters.map(counter => (
          <Counter
            key={counter.id}
            onIncrement={this.handleIncrement}

          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Counters;

//Child Component
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
   return (
      <div>

        <button
          onClick={() => this.props.onIncrement(this.props.counter)}

        >
          Increment
       </button>

}

export default Counter;
```

Comment: You have a syntax error, missing some curly brances --> `key={counter.id}`

Comment: Jayce444, you can write it in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the render section with this:

```
 render() {
    const { counters } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {counters.map(counter => {
            const counterKey = `counter-${counter.id}`;
            return (
                <Counter
                  key={counterKey}
                  onIncrement={this.handleIncrement}
                />
            )})
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: why not use `key={counter.id}`?

Comment: I retyped the handleIncrement method and it now works. I not sure as to what changed.